# Tomcat 6 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tomcat6

I am having problem with Tomcat 6.0 in Windows 7. I installed it to work with EasyEclipse Server Java and changed it's configuration to Manual. But now when I try to *Configure Tomcat*, I get *"Access is denied Unable to open the service 'Tomcat6'"*. Also now when I start and stop Tomcat within EasyEclipse I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost_\SESSIONS.ser (Access is denied)

Please help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have write permissions on `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\` Change the permissions on that directory, or install Tomcat somewhere else, where you do have permissions.

Answer (score 5):

right answer
Unable to open the service 'Tomcat6' on Windows Vista or Windows 7
If you receive the error message 
Unable to open the service 'Tomcat6'

when starting Tomcat on Windows Vista or Windows 7, this is likely caused by Windows User Access Control (UAC). To solve the problem, run Tomcat as an administrator (either by logging into Windows as an administrator or by right-clicking on the Tomcat Monitor and running this as an administrator. Alternatively, disabling UAC should also solve the problem.

You can find more information on UAC here:

Windows Vista: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx

Windows 7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx